# How to modify the label style of bibliography?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

I'm using `natbib` package and bibliography style `ama` which I would like to modify.
The reference list should be listed like this:

```
1. Kapur NK, Musunuru K. Clinical efficiency and safety of statins in
   managing cardiovascular risk. Vasc Health Risk Manag. 2008;4(2):341–353.
2.
3.
```

not:

```
[1] Kapur NK, Musunuru K. Clinical efficiency and safety of statins in
managing cardiovascular risk. Vasc Health Risk Manag. 2008;4(2):341–353.
[2]
[3]
```

Example file:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibpunct{}{}{,}{s}{}{,}

\begin{document}
\cite{48341}
\bibliographystyle{ama}
\bibliography{refs}
\end{document}
```

The bibliographical data in BibTeX format are available [here](http://scholar.harvard.edu/musunuru/publications/clinical-efficacy-and-safety-statins-managing-cardiovascular-risk).

How to do this?
Thank you

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The bibliography style is not in TeX Live, but here: [`CTAN:biblio/bibtex/contrib/misc/ama.bst`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/misc/ama.bst).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number format in the bibliography, set by `natbib` can be changed via `\bibnumfmt`:

```
\renewcommand*{\bibnumfmt}[1]{#1.}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibpunct{}{}{,}{s}{}{,}
\renewcommand*{\bibnumfmt}[1]{#1.}

\begin{document}
\noindent Citation\cite{48341}
\bibliographystyle{ama}
\bibliography{refs}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]